# How to split a string in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have the following line read in from my text file: `"1200, 1200"` and I want to split the string on the `", "` such that I can access the raw numbers. How can I do that in Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start, you may want to check out [this article on Splitting Strings in Julia](https://logankilpatrick.medium.com/the-only-way-you-should-be-splitting-a-string-in-julia-julia-base-split-374b191a543).

In scenarios like this (simple text file parsing) use `DelimetedFiles`. It is usually most robust and most straightforward to use.

Consider the following file:

```
open("file.txt","w") do f
    println(f, "1200, 2000, 3000\n1300, 4000, 5000")
end
```

And now let us read it

```
julia> using DelimitedFiles

julia> readdlm("file.txt", ',',Int)
2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1200  2000  3000
 1300  4000  5000
```

There are many parameters available to control the process but the beautiful thing is that their [default values](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/DelimitedFiles/) make the parsing process smart and straight-forward.

Comment: I think this is a better answer than the accepted one.

Answer (score 11):

[Check out this comprehensive article on Splitting Strings in Julia.](https://logankilpatrick.medium.com/the-only-way-you-should-be-splitting-a-string-in-julia-julia-base-split-374b191a543)

Julia has a simple `split` function which takes in two arguments. The first is the string you want to split and the second is the delimiter (the thing you want to split on/by). Both parameters that are passed to the split function should be strings.

In this example:

```
data = readlines("numbers.txt") # Returns a one dimensional array of strings. 
xmin, ymin = split(data[1], ", ") # data[1] indexs into that 1-D array to get the string
```

we read in all of the data from a text file which is just simple "1200, 1400".

We can then use the `split` function to separate the two numbers into "xmin" and "ymin". In this example, after the code is run, "xmin" will be equal to 1200 and "ymin" will be equal to 1400.

[Read more about the `split` function in the Julia docs.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.split)

Comment: This code results in strings, not 'numbers'. Use `[parse(Int, d) for d in split(data[1], ", ")]` to get what I would call numbers.